# How to reduce the number of loops for checking if an array of values is in between another array of ranges

Tags: javascript, performance, google-apps-script, big-o

I'm trying to check if a time is within an array of intervals, I know how to do the comparisons...etc However I am worried about efficiency becuase I need to check a lot of time entries (6,000,000) and I'm using a service that provides a limited amount of processing time.

Right now I have an array of 48 time ranges, it's a 24 hour day split into 30 minute intervals. I loop through this array with each of the 6000k entries to see which one the entry falls in between. So I need to perform 288,000,000 loops with 2 conditional checks per loop.

So this is pretty much O(n*48).

In what ways can this be improved? This is in JavaScript.

Edit Code as requested:

Example interval:

- Start: `new Date(0,0,0,1,30,0)`
- End: `new Date(0,0,0,2,0,1)`

Example Time: (I turn the time string into a date as shown in the second bullet)

- `'2015-12-03 15:25:00'`
- `new Date(0,0,0,15,25,0)`

Example Loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
{
    for(var ii = 0; ii < myIntervals.length; ii++)
    {
        if(myArray[i] >= myIntervals[ii].start && myArray[i] <= myIntervals[ii].end)
        {
            myIntervalCounts[ii] ++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please show some code, I don't get what kind of Data/Values your Arrays actually contain.

Comment: Sure, posted some code.

Comment: i don't see why you need a nested loop at all. the hour is part of your key, and a simple compare of `>30` on the mins will give you the key suffix. you don't need to parse it into a date or do a loop-de-loop...

Comment: Oh jeeze, that's so obvious, thanks Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what a understood on the problem, you have 6kk entries in the form "11:37 AM","10:00 PM" and 48 time splits of 30 min each, and you one label them (for instance, 11:37 AM is in the 23rd label, with 0 indexing).

I believe need only one loop over the time entries:

```
function label_timestamp(hour,minute,period)
   return hour*2 + (period==="PM")*24 + (minute>30)*1 )

for (e in entries) 
   console.log(label_timestamp(e.hour, e.minute, e.period)
```

This way 11:37 AM becomes `11*2+0*24+1*1=23`

This is O(n), but again, the question is not very clear.

Comment: Hey Eduardo, I posted some more info that might be helpful. Looking into your answer now.

Comment: Given the info I think this code will work ok. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

well, if your time-ranges line up, you could do sth like this:

```
var start = myIntervals[0].start, 
    end = myIntervals[myIntervals.length-1].end,
    segment = (end-start) / myIntervals.length;

for(var i=0, j=myArray.length; i<j; ++i){
    var v = myArray[i];

    if(v < start || v >= end) continue;
    var ii = ((v - start)/segment) >>> 0;
    myIntervalCounts[ii]++; 
}
```

assuming that the intervals are sorted, otherwise you would need to add some mapping